# Live camera in UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6

Does anybody know how I can get a live camera feed into an `UIImageView`?

I have a custom UI where I need to show the camera feed (front facing camera) so I cannot use the `UIImagePickerControl`.

Comment: Take a look at the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a capture session, and start it running. Once that's done you can add the layer from the capture session to your view:

```
- (void)setupCaptureSession
{
    NSError* error = nil;

    // Create the session
    _captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];    
    _captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
    AVCaptureDevice* device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    AVCaptureDeviceInput* input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];

    [_captureSession addInput:input];
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput* output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [_captureSession addOutput:output];

    // Configure your output.
   dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myCameraOutputQueue", NULL);
   //If you want to sebsequently use the data, then implement the delegate.
   [output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue]; 
}
```

Having done that, you can create a preview layer as follows:

```
_previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:_captureSession];
[_captureSession startRunning];
```

And then add the preview layer to your view:

```
_myView.layer addSubLayer:_previewLayer];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply! I've tried this, but the UIImageView is still not showing up the camera. I've replaced _myView with the UIImageView What to do now?

Comment: _myView is the name of the view you want to add the camera to. Can you try setting that view with: _camera.previewLayer.frame = _myView.bounds;

Comment: When running [_captureSession startRunning], it provides me the view... But then I get an exception.. Any idea?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22746/discussion-between-jasper-blues-and-cyberk)