# How to make a full screen landscape camera without any buttons?

Tags: objective-c, image

When the app launches I just want to make it display a camera view in full screen, without any on screen buttons, just the actual part which the camera is seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You wont want to use the camera then. There are multiple ways to do this, the quickest is through a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Check out this answer: [Get Camera Preview to AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515921/get-camera-preview-to-avcapturevideopreviewlayer)

```
- (void)initCapture
{
    AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *captureInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:inputDevice error:nil];
    if (!captureInput) {
        return;
    }
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *captureOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    /* captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection delegate method !*/
    [captureOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    NSString* key = (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey;
    NSNumber* value = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA];
    NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:value forKey:key];
    [captureOutput setVideoSettings:videoSettings];
    self.captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    NSString* preset = 0;
    if (!preset) {
        preset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
    }
    self.captureSession.sessionPreset = preset;
    if ([self.captureSession canAddInput:captureInput]) {
        [self.captureSession addInput:captureInput];
    }
    if ([self.captureSession canAddOutput:captureOutput]) {
        [self.captureSession addOutput:captureOutput];
    }

    //handle prevLayer
    if (!self.captureVideoPreviewLayer) {
        self.captureVideoPreviewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:self.captureSession];
    }

    //if you want to adjust the previewlayer frame, here!
    self.captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    self.captureVideoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer: self.captureVideoPreviewLayer];
    [self.captureSession startRunning];
}
```

Also see:

[Live camera in UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337489/live-camera-in-uiimageview)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Added that into viewcontroller.m. Comes up with error for - (void)initCapture   use of undeclared identifier 'initCapture'   then warning for @implementation ViewController. How do i fix this and also connect this code to the storyboard with what item to make the thing work

Comment: the error for @implementation ViewController is  Method  definition  for 'initCapture' not found